# Why is tpqoa's stream_data freezing after fetching just one tick from Oanda?

Tags: python-3.x, hft, oanda

I'm trying to use tpqoa to build my own automated bot to trade on Oanda. But the stream_data method keeps freezing after just getting one tick. Attached is the screenshot of my Jupyter Notebook, which has been frozen for almost an hour. Why is this happening? And how can I fix it?

[image: 1]

I called stream_data("EUR_USD", stop=20).

I expected to see 20 ticks within a couple minutes.

But I actually saw my Jupyter Notebook stuck for over an hour just after it got the first tick.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be if you are trying to use this outside of market hours.